# Changing only some path/group fills in a background image using svg-sprites

Tags: svg, background-image

I'm using svg as a background image (logo) in a WP menu plugin and i want it to change a color (fill) when hovered. As it's a free version of the plugin i can't use image, object etc - i have to use my svg as a background image. I've to support IE (9+) so masks/filters are out of question and i'm pretty much left with svg-sprites. That's okey, i know how to do it (using use/xlink:href).

But now comes a tricky part. I want my svg to change only fills of *some* groups/paths while hovered leaving others untouched. I can only change colors of *all* paths/groups together in a background image with svg-sprites afaik. Is there a way to do it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: here's the even trickier part: background images are not interactive, nor do they have an externally accessible DOM. You could have two (or more) background images and swap between them.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of that. Was just hoping there's some trick so i can do it with sprites instead of another query/inline svg-image (there're quite a lot of paths/groups in the image).